# How to get a .NET core 3.1 Project work with .NET 5.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

When .NET 5.0 was released, one of the features mentioned was the ability to create a .NET 5.0 component, that it would work with .NET 3.1, so you wouldn't have to use .net standard between different versions.

Well, I tried to use .net 3.1 with .net 5.0 and I keep getting errors.  Is there something special we have to do to make these work?  We have multiple applications at my company that use various versions of .NET core.  from 2.2, 3.0, 3.1 to .net 5.0.  We would like to create some NuGet packages for some of the reusable components, but trying to figure out how to use .net core through out these applications, I don't want to create them with .net standard.

Has anyone run into this or not?

Comment: Would be great if you could tell us what errors you have. Can you add them to the question please?

Answer (score 0):

A .net 5.0 library/dll cannot be referenced from a .net version less than .net 5.0.  .net standard 2.1 should be used for compatibility between the different versions of .net core and .net 5.0.

On another note - its probably best to update all .net core projects to 5.0 assuming this is possible. The End of Life has been reached on .net core versions <= 3.0 (not .net standard).

see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-releases-and-support/).

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the errors, but despite that, it can already be said that `.NET 5` does not ensure backwards compatibility. Microsoft provides information on compatibility and breaking changes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/).

`.NET 5` merges together `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core`, ending the burden of keeping both; the aim is to also include `Mono` and `Xamarin` (`MAUI`). However, it does not ensure compatibility with previous versions. [This](https://intellitect.com/dotnet-5/) is a good article on the subject - some features were delayed to `.NET 6` though.

Hence, the best ways for you to have the compatibility you want would be to use `.NET Standard` or, even better, migrate the applications to `.NET 5`, since previous versions' support will end soon. In the team I work, we made some migrations from `.NET Core 3.x` to `.NET 5` and it was pretty straightforward.

It is worth noticing that `.NET 5` is not LTS. `.NET 6`, on the other hand, is. More details on .NET releases and support policies [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).